# Crashes in deflateEnd of zlib

Tags: android, zlib

My program is an android app, and crashes in deflateEnd(&strm) of zlib. 
I am using zlib to compress a network traffic stream. My zlib code is below.

First, init the deflate.

Then, when the stream buffer data has arrived, call deflate to compress.

And then, when my stream encounters EOF, my program crashes in 
`deflateEnd()`.

Except for above call， `zstream_` is only used in some initial code like`memset(&zstream_, 0, sizeof(zstream_));` I think they have little influence on my crash.

By the way, this is a online and sometimes issue. It occurs about 50 times in tens of thousands of running. I am so sorry for that I cannot provide a simple verifiable example now. But I will try.

In addition， I doubt that the my usage of Z_SYNC_FLUSH is not correct.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. You haven't even shown the `deflateEnd()` call. Take the code that results in the crash and remove as much code, calls, function structures, etc. as you can, and still have it crash. Most likely you are overwriting the `z_stream` structure inadvertently due to exceeding the bounds of another structure.

Comment: I have upload the call of deflateEnd, and try to explain where the `zstream_` also exists. I am so sorry that I cannot provide a example now,  because it is a online, sometimes isse. But I will try.

Comment: what I want to figure out is if my usage of deflate to handle network traffic stream from evbuffer of libevent is not correct.

Comment: You need to understand that your usage of deflate might be perfectly fine (can't tell), but something _else_ in your code may be overrunning a buffer or causing a stack overflow. (In which case you came to the right site!)